# Pointcut for a method injected with AspectJ

Tags: java, aspectj, aspect

How can I define a pointcut for a method injected with ApsectJ?

I have injected the method as follows and it works properly:

```java
public void com.moeActivity.onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
    Log.d("ATAG", "BACKK");
}
```

Now am trying to define a pointcut to detect the execution of the injected method but it is not successful, I tried the following:

```java
pointcut eventActivity(): 
  execution(* com.moeActivity.onBackPressed(..));
```

Any help would be appreciated

Thanks!

Comment: What is the real question? What do you want to achieve? You have a method and a pointcut. Probably you also want to define an advice which actually injects some functionality at all matches joinpoints, don't you? BTW, have you read an AspectJ tutorial?

Answer (score 0):

You need an advice body to run the enjected method (e.g. `Log.d("ATAG", "BACKK")` probably) inside of it like this:

```
public aspect LoggingAspect{
 after() : eventActivity() {
   Log.d("ATAG", "BACKK");
 } 
}
```

Doing this, the after advice connects with the named pointcut called eventActivity and runs the crosscutting action (i.e. `Log.d("ATAG", "BACKK")`) after `super.onBackPressed()`. As @kriegaex says, you need to read some AspectJ examples to comprehend it efficiently.